# getActivity cannot resolve method from fragment

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have to create an ArrayAdapter, but when I put getActivity() into the constructor it says `cannot resolve method getActivity()`

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.ProtocolException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.lang.Void;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.content.Context;


                public class HttpURLConnectionExample extends AsyncTask<ListView, Void, String> {

                    public ListView myList = null;

                    public void sendGet(ListView lv){
                        myList = lv;
                        this.execute();
                        return;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(ListView... arg0) {
                        String url = "http://192.168.1.9";
                        URL obj = null;
                        try{
                            obj = new URL(url);}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        HttpURLConnection con = null;
                        try{
                            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();}
                        catch(IOException e){}

                        //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                        try{
                            con.setRequestMethod("GET");}
                        catch(ProtocolException e){}
                        try{
                            con.connect();}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        try{
                            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        BufferedReader in = null;
                        try{
                            in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        String inputLine;
                        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                        try{
                            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                response.append(inputLine);
                            }}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        try{
                            in.close();}
                        catch(IOException e){}
                        //print result
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                        return response.toString();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        String strParts[] = result.split("@");
                        ArrayList<dispencer> listAr = new ArrayList<dispencer>();
                        for(int i=0; i<strParts.length; i++){
                            listAr.add( new dispencer(strParts[i]) );
                        }

                        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < listAr.size(); ++i) {
                            adapter.add(listAr.get(i).toString());
                        }
                        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
                        return ;
                    }

            }
```

I read i had to use getActivity method since i'm in a fragment and not in context. 
EDIT i coudn't extend my MainActivity Class because this class already extend asyncTask.

Comment: Show your file, does your class extend Fragment class? You have the Fragment class included in your imports right?

Comment: You are not in the fragment, you are in AsyncTask, which is not context, and does not have getActivity() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not extending fragment class. So you need to do following things.

**when you want to use context in asynctask class .you need to pass context in class constructor.**

example

```
public class MyCustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long> {

private Context mContext;

public MyCustomTask (Context context){
     mContext = context;
} 

//other methods like onPreExecute etc. 
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     Toast.makeText(mContext,"Its working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
} }
```

And instantiate class by following.

```
MyCustomTask task = new MyCustomTask(context);
task.execute(..);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all be sure that you imported the Fragment class and made your fragment extent it.
define a variable with Type

```
Context mContext ;
```

then initial this variable with getActivity() like this

```
mContext=getActivity();
```

the pass this variable to your Adapter

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
```

Comment: I believe saving it in a variable and then using it won't make a difference. In the end, the same value ends up as the argument to the adapter.

Comment: your class doesn't extend Fragment class so getActivity() will be not valid @KetanMalhotra

Comment: "your"? I didn't ask the question. I suggested the same before you as comment to Raffa (OP). I just meant that saving the value of getActivity() to a variable won't solve the problem.

Comment: I am so sorry. I think you asked the question. I am also suggest to import Fragment Class an be sure that his fragment class extend the parent class Fragment @KetanMalhotra

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `AsyncTask` not `Fragment` class, pass a `Context` or `Activity` reference to Constructor instead:

`public MyTask(Context context)` and store a reference to it in your Task.